# Beginner having a problem with classes

Tags: python, class

I'm working through O'Reilly's "Learning Python" and having a problem with classes. I think I  understand the concept, but in practice have stumbled upon this problem.
Fron page 88-89:

```
>>> class Worker:
def __innit__(self, name, pay):
    self.name=name
    self.pay=pay
    def lastName(self):
        return self.name.split()[-1]
    def giveRaise(self, percent):
        self.pay*=(1.0+percent)
```

Then the book says "Calling the class like a function generates instances of a new type ...etc" and gives this example.

```
bob = Worker('Bob Smith', 50000)
```

This gives me this error:

TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments.

And then I start muttering profanities. So what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Python as Ali G (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_G) would write it.

Answer (score 8):

David, you've mis-typed `__init__`

The correct spelling is this:

```
def __init__(self, name, pay):
    self.name=name
    self.pay=pay
def lastName(self):
    return self.name.split()[-1]
def giveRaise(self, percent):
    self.pay*=(1.0+percent)
```

Comment: This is my emabarassed face. Thanks very much.

Comment: That sure is a lot of upvotes for preserving the OP's indentation mistake :)

Comment: Copy-paste is a harsh mistress, sometimes :) I'll confess, I didn't read the rest of the code once I'd spotted the initial error.  Edited for correctness, now.

Answer (score 5):

One misspelling: it's `__init__`, not `__innit__` -- just one `n`.

You also have some indentation problems but I think those may be due to just copy-and-paste issues, or else you'd be getting `SyntaxError`s before the `TypeError` you relate;-).

So your code should probably be:

```
class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, name, pay):
        self.name=name
        self.pay=pay
    def lastName(self):
        return self.name.split()[-1]
    def giveRaise(self, percent):
        self.pay*=(1.0+percent)
```

I've also added the `(object)` to `class Worker` -- in Python 3.* it doesn't matter, but in 2.* it does (and even in 3.* it doesn't hurt, anyway;-).  This makes the class "new style", which doesn't matter at very elementary levels but will as soon as you start wanting to do anything "cool and interesting" such as adding properties;-).

Comment: Thanks for the freebie (object) tip.:)

Comment: @David, you're welcome -- and make sure you also indent like in my answer, **not** like in @Chris's, or else those `lastName` and `giveRaise` would be nested functions within `__init__` and not visible outside of it!-)

Answer (score 2):

You wrote `__innit__` instead of `__init__`.

In this way, you declared just another method in the class, not the special method called the constructor, which is by definition named `__init__`. This causes Python to generate a default constructor taking no arguments, hence the error message.

Comment: This causes Python to generate a default constructor taking no arguments, hence the error message.

Thanks for that.